# Anchor Error, Refuses to build and deploy

Tags: anchor-lang, cargo, build-bpf

I was downgrading and upgrading my Solana and anchor versions in order to deploy my programs to devnet. And while doing that after a time my anchor broke. I removed the rust and re-installed it and anchor but the problem is still there. This is what happens when I run anchor build.

BPF SDK: /home/a/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.25/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf

cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v

cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain link bpf /home/a/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.25/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/rust

cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release

error: process didn't exit successfully: `rustc -vV` (exit status: 127)
--- stderr

/home/a/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/rustc: error while loading shared libraries: librustc_driver-0a24654c7f10b1f7.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: The last time this happened, I had to reinstall Rust. I didn't look into the root cause tho.

Comment: I did that, did not solve the problem for me

Comment: I downgraded solana version to 1.10.10 and resinstalled rust and was able to fix this

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this, by uninstalling rust, reinstalling rust(1.61.0) and anchor (0.24.2)and downgrading solana from 1.11.10 to 1.10.10.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for one user (biccsdev), instead of reinstalling both Rust and Anchor and downgrading Solana:

```
cargo update -p syn --precise 1.0.99; cargo update -p proc-macro2 --precise 1.0.43
```